# Creating polygons from lines using ArcEditor/Standard level license of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line, geometry-conversion, standard-license-level

I am trying to create polygons from a line layer of lots and concessions (large blocks of land in rural areas).

The lines are mainly grid style as they intersect mostly at right angles.

I need to create polygons from these lines.

I tried it in QGIS and it did not work.

Any suggestions other than digitizing?

I'm using ArcEditor 10.

Answer (score 21):

I discovered a page named [Constructing polygons from the shapes of other features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/creating-new-features/constructing-polygons-from-the-geometry-of-other-features.htm) on Esri's site that should allow you to contruct polygons from your lines with only an ArcEditor/Standard license. You can select the lines you want to convert to polygons, then use the Construct Polygons button on the Topology toolbar (ArcGIS 10.0 or earlier) or the Advanced Editing toolbar (ArcGIS 10.1 or later).

If only you had an ArcInfo/Advanced license, you'd be able to use the Feature to Polygon tool that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

**ET Geowizards** will easily convert Polylines to Polygons (preserving attribution)

http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm

Current Version is  ET GeoWizards 10.1  (released 12 November 2011)

Credit goes to Ianko Tchoukanski for producing and maintaining this excellent ArcGIS tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can try XTools  - Make Polygons from Polylines

http://www.xtoolspro.com/tools.asp

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use tool create polygon from lines.
Please see this.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/tutorials/Editor_Ex7_10.htm

How to access this command in ArcGIS 10 please see this

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38276

Answer (score 1):

For small numbers of features, read Hardolph's answer on [this thread](https://community.esri.com/thread/7568):

> 1. start by making sure the line segments are either snapped together or overlap and set snapping in the polyline layer. Make sure no
>      polygons are present within the area.
> 2. select all the segments with the edit tool; with Task:  Create New Feature  and Target: the FC the polylines are in and hit MERGE in the
>      editor pull down.
> 3. leaving merged line selected change "Target:" to a polygon layer and "Task:" to "Auto-complete Polygon"
> 4. snap the SKETCH tool to the merged line and RIGHT-click and select "replace sketch" from the pull-down menu.
> 5. all the vertices should show up; hit F2 or right-click again and hit Finish Sketch.
>
> That will generate a polygon even in ArcView (9.2, 9.3).  I've use it
>   regularly.  I put up some previous posts describing this workaround
>   for ArcView, but if you have ArcInfo the main thing is probably to get
>   the line segments to close.

Works like a charm for all licence levels.

Comment: All questions and answers here should be standalone.  It is fine to support them with links but always try to include at least a summary or quote from that link within your answer.