# How to convert a line shapefile to a polygon shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcmap, polygon, convert, line

I am using Arcgis 10.1 and have an existing line shapefile that i would like to convert to polygons.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help although it is slightly outdated: [How to create polygons from lines?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19077/how-to-create-polygons-from-lines).

Comment: This YouTube video shows a method that works at 10.1 for any license level.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ilt_yfdn90g

Answer (score 2):

See arcgis help: Creating polygons from lines

http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//01m600000015000000